Error on packaeg Check - family or concept entries that could possibly lead to multiple index terms
I have the following file in my R package. I'm not sure why I get the error.
Here is the code:
#' Diagnosis to Condition Code Mapping file
#'
#' @family AHRQ
#'
#' AHRQ DX Condition Codes.
#'
#' @docType data
#' @name dx_cc_mapping
#' @usage data(dx_cc_mapping)
#' @format A data frame with 86852 rows and 5 variables
"dx_cc_mapping"

#' Procedure to Condition Code Mapping file
#'
#' @family AHRQ
#'
#' AHRQ Px Condition Codes.
#'
#' @docType data
#' @name px_cc_mapping
#' @usage data(px_cc_mapping)
#' @format A data frame with 79721 rows and 5 variables
"px_cc_mapping"

Here is the error:
   Found the following \keyword or \concept entries
   which likely give several index terms:
     File 'dx_cc_mapping.Rd':
       \concept{AHRQ
         
         AHRQ DX Condition Codes.}
     File 'px_cc_mapping.Rd':
       \concept{AHRQ
         
         AHRQ Px Condition Codes.}

Update
I fixed it by doing this:
#' Diagnosis to Condition Code Mapping file
#'
#' @family AHRQ_Dx
#' @docType data
#' @name dx_cc_mapping
#' @usage data(dx_cc_mapping)
#' @format A data frame with 86852 rows and 5 variables
"dx_cc_mapping"

#' Procedure to Condition Code Mapping file
#'
#' @family AHRQ_Px
#' @docType data
#' @name px_cc_mapping
#' @usage data(px_cc_mapping)
#' @format A data frame with 79721 rows and 5 variables
"px_cc_mapping"


Out of curiosity, what was the actual issue? the description and line breaks after the @family tag or the non-unique @family values?

It took the line after the @family tag as part of the concept
